# color balance effect with SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg, filter

I need to apply a filter "color balance" on my image using CSS and SVG filter,

so how can I add a filter color-balance and how can I be back to original color in image

this is my code but I didn't see any changement

```
<html> 
<style>
#filt{
filter:url(feColor-balance.svg#balance);
}
</style>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="balance">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
            values="1.3 0 0 0 0
                0 1.1 0 0 0
                0 0 0.7 0 0
                0 0 0 1 0"/>
    </filter>
</defs>

<image xlink:href="http://www.mivision.com.au/uploads/ufiles/xx/oct/mv_Feb_Feature_eyes_in_art_My_beautiful_retina.jpg" x="5" y="5" width="190" height="290"/>

<image xlink:href="http://www.mivision.com.au/uploads/ufiles/xx/oct/mv_Feb_Feature_eyes_in_art_My_beautiful_retina.jpg" id="filt" x="205" y="5" width="190" height="290"/>


</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter is in the same file so it's just #balance and not feColor-balance.svg unless that's what you've called your html file which would be unusual.

Also you need to supply width and height values for the svg element otherwise it will only work on Chrome until their SVG sizing bug gets fixed.

```
<html> 
<style>
#filt{
filter:url(#balance);
}
</style>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
    <filter id="balance">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
            values="1.3 0 0 0 0
                0 1.1 0 0 0
                0 0 0.7 0 0
                0 0 0 1 0"/>
    </filter>
</defs>

<image xlink:href="http://www.mivision.com.au/uploads/ufiles/xx/oct/mv_Feb_Feature_eyes_in_art_My_beautiful_retina.jpg" x="5" y="5" width="190" height="290"/>

<image xlink:href="http://www.mivision.com.au/uploads/ufiles/xx/oct/mv_Feb_Feature_eyes_in_art_My_beautiful_retina.jpg" id="filt" x="205" y="5" width="190" height="290"/>


</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, so do you know wich values of matrix should I put to get the original color ?

Comment: [1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 1 0](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement) is the identity filter is that what you meant?